# Jarsigner works fine, NetBeans jnlp does not

Tags: java, signing, netbeans-platform

I am on Windows

I deleted all instances of Java so that I know which one was  actually using then installed the current version of the jdk.

I am able to sign my jar file with jarsigner, but, using the same settings and credentials, NetBeans fails trying to sign the jar file. I'm not in front of my computer, but the error was saying that the alias did not exist in the keystore (or something to that effect.)

Comment: how are you doing it on netbeans? ant, maven...?

Comment: Ant is called from NetBeans and configured with the jnlp configuration tool inside of NetBeans

Answer (score 0):

I finally gave up on Netbeans' ability to create a signed jar file.  I created a brand new project with a regular java target.  I removed the HelloWorld file it put there and copied all of my files from the original (jnlp) project into this new one.  I had already written my own jnlp file that I was using so I I added the following to my build.xml:

```
  <target name="-post-jar">
    <copy file="web/my-original.jnlp" todir="${dist.jar.dir}"/>
    <signjar destDir="${dist.jar.dir}"
           alias="my-alias" 
           keystore="my-keystore"
           storepass="my-password"
           tsaurl="http://timestamp.digicert.com"
           preservelastmodified="true">
      <path>
        <fileset dir="${dist.jar.dir}" includes="**/*.jar" />
      </path>
      <flattenmapper />
    </signjar>
  </target>
```